# Style spree admin pannel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I am working on a spree store and I have been able to style the frontend just fine by setting up my style sheets in the same folder structure as spree has but I am trying to change the font and colors in the admin panel and I can not get anything to work. This is my current css structure:

app/assets/stylesheets/spree/backend/global/_variables.scss

```
  @font-face {
  font-family: "lato";
  src: font-url("lato.ttf");
}
/*------------------------------------------
  Fonts
  -----------------------------------------*/
  $headings-font-family: lato;
  $headings-font-weight: 300;

/*------------------------------------------
  Colors
  -----------------------------------------*/
  $brand-primary: #FF5C5E;
  $brand-success: #FF5C5E;
  $brand-info:    #FF5C5E;
  $brand-warning: #505050;
  $brand-danger:  #505050;

  $input-border:  darken(#EDEDED, 5);
```

Comment: Was this intentional "`Fonts
  -----------------------------------------*/`"?

Comment: Yeah in my code that is commented out, I just missed it when I copied and pasted... Ill edit to fix that